# Design select SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have three values expected in a table case, Serious, Non-Serious, Unknown for each `case_id`

```
select case_id, case_seriousness 
from case;
```

I have to build a SQL query which should show one row per `case_id`.

If there are rows for a `case_id` with multiple values, then only one row should appear based on priority - Serious, Non-Serious then Unknown.

e.g. Serious is in one row rest of four rows have Non-Serious or Unknown then Serious will be he value to show in one record.

If there are records with Non-serious and Unknown then Non-Serious should appear.

So Priorities will be like from S, NS and UK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the analytical function as follows:

```
select case_id, case_seriousness 
  from
      (select case_id, case_seriousness, 
              row_number() over (partition by case_id 
                                 order by case case_seriousness 
                                               when 'Serious' then 1 
                                               when 'Non-Serious' then 2
                                               else 3 
                                           end ) as rn 
          from case)
where rn = 1;
```

Alternatively, You can also use `DECODE` instead of `CASE..WHEN`

Comment: Thanks for replying, I missed other conditions there can be a scenario that serious row is not there... please see

Comment: then this query will return NS record, if NS is also null then it will show UK record

Comment: Because of your table name. Case is oracle reserved keyword. You should use your table name as `"CASE"`

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, case wasn't an issue something else... query ran just looking for post and pre data to be matched

Comment: You mentioned in your last comment - *It shows an error, invalid sql statement* So what is the issue that now you are facing?

Comment: Suppose there are 4 rows it is faching first row data as rn = 1 no matter what value it consists

Comment: I have used `order by case case_seriousness when 'Serious' then 1 when 'Non-Serious' then 2 else 3 end` to give numbers. Please correct the string values if they are not correct

Comment: ohkk I got it,, and there is no error  as of now... I was just wondering about pre and post query mismatched count...

Comment: If you think it resolved your question then you should accept this answer so that your question is marked as resolved